# переливание и преломление текстур на модели

Tags: unity3d

В чем беда:

(переливаются и рябят текстуры на моделях)

Кто-то встречался с такой проблемой?
`Clipping Planes` не помогает. (это на камере, где `Near` и `Far`).

Связи с чем это может происходить и как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, нужно было использовать сглаживание и отключить режим `Deferred` и `HDR`, так как из-за них не получалось ничего.